# replace values in series according to threshold

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a pandas series and I would like to replace the values with 0 if the value < 3 and with 1 if the value >=3

```
se = pandas.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6])
se[se<3]=0
se[se>=3]=1
```

Is there a better/pythonic way to do so?

Comment: I think everything is OK with your implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion here is best/fast cast boolean mask to `integer`s:

```
se = (se >= 3).astype(int)
```

Or use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), but `Series` constructor is necessary, because returned numpy array:

```
se = pd.Series(np.where(se < 3, 0, 1), index=se.index)

print (se)
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas
se = pandas.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6])
print(se.apply(lambda x: 1 if x >=3 else 0))
```

**Output:**

```
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
dtype: int64
```